# Search for configuration (like Super-A for Applications, Super-F for Files)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, usability

Is there a way to search for configuration settings, like Super-A for Applications, Super-F for Files?

I want to type in: "shortcuts" and then I want to see a list of things which match this term.

The concrete example for "shortcuts" is just one example. I now how to find this configuration now :-)

Yes, I am lazy. Even better would be a "search everything".

In my use case I want to search for custom keyboard shortcuts, since the new version of diodon (clipboard manager) needs this ([explanation](https://esite.ch/2015/07/using-custom-shortcuts-of-de-as-diodon-hotkey/)).

I want to find the matching config dialog by typing, not by following a guide of nested menu clicks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are looking for. A way to find set keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: If you right click onto dash icon you have list of "shorrcuts" to open specific dash menu.  As for shortcuts,  there are two ways, GUI via system settings  and command line.

Comment: Just type keyboard shortcut and go there

Comment: @Anwar I hit the Super key, then typed in "shortcut" and no result was found. I use Ubuntu 16.04.